# How do I annotate a division with the numerator and denominator vertically aligned and separated by a horizontal line

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, division

I'm currently trying to add an annotation to my ggplot which displays the fraction `1/9` in the specific format shown in the image I've provided. Despite it seeming like a straightforward task, I find myself stuck and unable to figure out the correct way to accomplish this. Any guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Here is an example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
  geom_point()+
  annotate("text", x = 3, y = 3, label = "1/9", size = 10, color = "red") +
  coord_cartesian()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to add a fraction would be to use `?plotmath`, i.e. to create your fraction you could use `label = "frac(1, 9)"` and set `parse=TRUE` in `annotate()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate("text",
    x = 5, y = 30, label = "frac(1, 9)", size = 10, color = "red",
    parse = TRUE
  ) +
  coord_cartesian()
```

[image]